# Google Visual Chart - MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

```html
<?php
     $username="@@@@";  
     $password="@@@@";  
     $hostname = "@@@@@";  
     $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);  
     $query = "SELECT TYPE, count(*) as number FROM @@@@ GROUP BY TYPE";  
     $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query);  
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Testing Site </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Type', 'Number'],
          <?php  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    echo "['".$row["TYPE"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";  
}  
?>
        ]);
        var options = {
          title: 'Percentage of Ticket Tyle',
          is3D: true,
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <br /><br />
    <div style="width:900px;">
      <h3 align="center">Testing 3D Pie Chart</h3>
      <br />
      <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

I have a table in my DB that has all kinds of ticket and each ticket has a COLUMN = "Type". I'm attempting to create a visual 3D chart showing how many different types of tickets there are. For example, it there's 10 tickets and 2 is for RED and 8 is for BLUE, I want the chart to show that.

The table doesn't have any numeral values explaining the number of type each has appeared so my query is listed above.

The graph is not showing up, so question is WHY.
Please assist.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Don't hand-roll your own JSON. Use [`json_encode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: any errors in the browser's console?